# div inside table with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, dom

I have table with some data, and some other data I get with ajax. 
I need to know how to display the response inside the table?

Code:

```
<?php $x = 1; foreach ($projects as $project){
           echo "<tr class=\"parent\">";
           echo "<td><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-down\"></td>";
           echo "<td class=\"pid\">$project[pid]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[status]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[project_title]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[notes]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[responsible]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[start_date]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[completed_date]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[duration]</td>";
           echo "<td>$project[completed]</td></tr>";
           echo "<div class=\"cchild\" id=\"txtHint$x\">";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "</tbody>";
            $x++;
          }
```

The data should show inside the div element. As far as I know it's not allowed to put the div inside the table, but any other idea. How to get the data properly inside the table.

Comment: Put it inside a table cell.

Comment: You need to generate valid html that can be added to a table to begin with; your last 3 echoes should probably be removed completely. And you need to show the current html - and where you want to add your response - and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to initialize a var with starting **div** and **table** tag and then in the for loop you can compute and append the tr **td** **tags** to the var. Once the loop is completed you can append the closing tags of **div** and **table** and the final output of the var will be **table**. Reference code:

```
$project = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $div = "<div><table><thead></thead><tbody>";
    foreach ($project as $p){
            $div.="<tr><td>".$p."</td></tr>";
    }
    $div.="</tbody></table></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty tr with in table with specific class like

```
    <?php $x = 1; foreach ($projects as $project){
       echo "<tr class=\"parent\">";
       echo "<td><i class=\"fa fa-chevron-down\"></td>";
       echo "<td class=\"pid\">$project[pid]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[status]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[project_title]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[notes]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[responsible]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[start_date]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[completed_date]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[duration]</td>";
       echo "<td>$project[completed]</td></tr>";
       echo "<tr><td><div class="cchild"></div></td></tr>";
       echo "</tbody>";
        $x++;
      }
```

Then replace the cchild div content with your ajax response.